# precompile coffeescript files ( Rails 4 )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, asset-pipeline, precompile

In my Rails 4 app I have a `users.js.coffee` file in `app/assets/javascripts`. It compiles and works fine in development. But when I deploy to heroku it's not working. According to Railsguides:

The matcher (and other members of the precompile array; see below) is applied to final compiled file names. This means anything that compiles to JS/CSS is excluded, as well as raw JS/CSS files; for example, .coffee and .scss files are not automatically included as they compile to JS/CSS.

So I added the following line to my `config/environments/production.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += %w ( users.js.coffee )
```

It's still not forcing the file to be precompiled. Do you know how I may force Rails to precompile it (I use `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` to precompile)?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `config.assets.precompile` should contain `users.js`, not `users.js.coffee`.